# why my ion card is not hiding in real android device but works in browser

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

why my `ion-card` is not hiding in real `android` `device` but works in `browser`

**here is Demo:**https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3bw7da?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

here is my code

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
   host: {'(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',} 
})

  public showMoreBarItem = false; 

   counter:number = -1;

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }


  presentPopover(event: Event){

    this.showMoreBarItem = !this.showMoreBarItem; 

    this.counter = 0;


  }


   onClick(event) {


       if(!(this.counter % 2 === 0)){         
           this.showMoreBarItem = false;              
       }

       this.counter++;


  }
```

> i'm unable to determine why it is not working on real android device?

**here is Demo:**https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3bw7da?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

**Please help me to find the solution,if possible by compiling for android**

Thank You in Advance!!!

Comment: Which ion-card is not hiding on click of presentPopover this function?

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, the only ion-card I can find is in the home.html, and it has a *ngIf="showAccountSettingClickedItem", but I don't see that variable declared in your home.ts. Maybe try declaring it and use it to define when to show the card or not.